# Question paper with Bloom's Taxonomy in exam document class

Tags: counters, exam, examdesign

I want to create a question paper in `exam` document class where the questions are marked with different knowledge levels from Revised Bloom's Taxonomy (RBT). There are six levels:

1. Remembering (`R`)
2. Understanding (`U`)
3. Applying (`Ap`)
4. Analysing (`An`)
5. Evaluating (`E`)
6. Creating (`C`)

I want the appearance of the questions as follows:
[image]

I want to achieve the followings:

1. I will write `\question{R}[2]` to obtain the followings:

   - Print the word '*(Remembering)*' in front of the question as shown in the picture.
   - Print the points of the question in the right margin as shown in the picture.
   - Start two counters for `R` keeping the number of 'Remembering' questions, and total points for the 'Remembering' questions.
2. To have the above privilege for all the RBT levels.
3. To have the above two privileges for all part questions as well: `\question`, `\part`, `\subpart`, `\subsubpart`. *The counter for number of questions will simply increase for every part question of the same kind.*
4. To have a command like `\printRBTtable` to print a table with RBT levels against their respective number of questions and total marks assigned for that level.
5. (*Optional*) To be able to print the `\printRBTtable` at the beginning of the question paper.

I know that I am asking a lot, but I will humbly appreciate any guidance on what should be done. Please include some resource materials for your suggestions.

[This link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnNh_584BiIjhbp2ICnm8stGBjkrLQ?e=uKsIly) contains a sample question paper to serve both as an MWE and as a template of how I am managing so far.

**Edit:** An MWE

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt, answers]{exam}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in, includefoot, footskip=3ex]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\setlength\@rightmargin{0.5in}
\patchcmd\setup@point@toks{\llap{\padded@point@block}}{\rlap{\padded@point@block}}{}{}
\patchcmd\droppoints{\llap{\padded@point@block}}{\rlap{\padded@point@block}}{}{}
\patchcmd\droptotalpoints{\llap{\total@block}}{\rlap{\total@block}}{}{}
\patchcmd\droptotalbonuspoints{\llap{\bonustotal@block}}{\rlap{\bonustotal@block}}{}{}
\makeatother\marksnotpoints
\bracketedpoints
\pointsdroppedatright
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Answer Keys:}\enspace}
\renewcommand\partlabel{(\textbf{\alph{partno}})}
\renewcommand{\thesubpart}{(\textit{\roman{subpart}})}
\renewcommand{\subpartlabel}{\thesubpart}
\renewcommand\questionlabel{\textbf{\thequestion.}}
\renewcommand\questionshook{\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{\makebox[15pt]{##1}}}}
%
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question[2]
            (\emph{Remembering}) Write the transformation formula if the coordinate axes undergoes a rotation followed by a translation.\droppoints
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please include the code inside the link here in your question. Links tend to disappear over time … Thank you

Comment: Actually it contains an entire question paper with 366 lines of code. This is a [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/6L4kXwEf).

Comment: @CarLaTeX Added in the Edit.

Comment: You can try `xsim` package

Comment: Anyone looking for an answer to this question may find it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713776/162028).